# How to get a list of all folders or a tree of a GitHub directory using JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, github, github-api

In the description of my tutorials I link people to a GitHub folder to get source material or final material of a lesson. On the website I want to set up a mini application that will make a "filter/search" for my lessons, that will link you to a needed folder. What I need is to get a list of all folders inside a specific GitHub repository, so that I can list them and get links to them.

Links or HTTP requests with explanations will help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you googled for something like `github api list files` before asking your question? See: https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents